# python gtk webkit with CSS, issue in Width

Tags: python, css, webkit, gtk, pygtk

I am creating a desktop app using Python GTK and WebKit. Mostly based on [this tutorial](http://www.aclevername.com/articles/python-webgui/).

I was creating my view in HTML5 and using CSS.

Problem is when i'm using `width:100%` or `repeat-x` the width of my window is keeps getting increased upto infinity.

i tried to put `max-width:100%` in `<body>` but it din't help.

for now, i made it fix width which is working fine, but i want to make he window resizable and so all the content inside without making it looking ugly.

Any help or work-around for this?

**UPDATE**

I am using the same code as given in this tutorial

http://www.aclevername.com/articles/python-webgui/

In the HTML file i just added one Header and Footer. For footer i just created a div,

```
 <div id="footer" style="width:100%; 
 position:absolute; align:center; bottom:0px; padding-top:10px; 
height:50px; background:url(img/int-bg.png) left top;">
</div>
```

Which is making thids window to expand its width infinitely.

if i fix the width in CSS then it won't do the expansion. and work fine, for fixed size window.

```
 <div id="footer" style="width:800px;
 position:absolute; align:center; bottom:0px; padding-top:10px; 
height:50px; background:url(img/int-bg.png) left top;">
</div>
```

but i want to make it re-sizable. how to achieve that flexibility?

Comment: can you supply some minimal code? And what happens if you don't set width to your GTK-window?

Comment: Hi @deinonychusaur did an update in my Question. i just run the same example with an additional footer div. and got this trouble. Thanks for your time in advance

Answer (score 1):

This may help (I've included some context to help other readers see that this is an issue involving PyWebKitGtk wanting to resize its parent container),

```
import gtk
import webkit

window = gtk.Window()
browser = webkit.WebView()
box = gtk.VBox(homogeneous=False, spacing=0)
window.add(box)
# ...
box.pack_start(browser, expand=True, fill=True, padding=0)
browser.set_size_request(400, 600) # <-- constrain width and height of browser
window.show_all()
```

The problem occurs because: setting "width: 100%" would result in overflow scrolling. But in this Gtk example, it instead triggers a resize that makes the parent window grow larger. Because the parent just grew larger, "width: 100%" now represents slightly more space, which results in an unstable feedback cycle.

A better solution may be to adjust padding and margins, etc. so that they do not trigger a resize at all when requesting "width: 100%". For example, using the CSS reset here seems to do the trick: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

I am also the author of the article, and glad that it is still giving inspiration despite that the article is also getting dated.

Comment: Thanks @david-baird Thanks a lot, it worked, just by consgtraining the width and height.

i'll see a the CSS Reset too.

Comment: Just a curious question, since it feels like there should be a better way than demanding of the web-page css to fit a certain spec., and since it feels a bit awkward to demand that the browser has a fit size, what happens if you put the browser in a `gtk.ScrolledWindow`?